# How to increase Bootstrap navbar-brand font-size?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, fonts, font-size

I've got a basic bootstrap navbar with a brand in there. The start of my html looks like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="navbar navbar-white navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">MyAwesomeCompany</a>
                etc.
```

which looks like this:

[image]

I now want to change the font to `Lato` and increase the font, so I added the following to the `<head>`:

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<style>
.navbar-brand
{
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  color:grey;
  font-size: 100px;
  margin: 0px;
}
</style>
```

but now it looks like this:

[image]

As you can see in the css I tried increasing the font-size to 100 pixels, but it stays so small. Does anybody know what I can do to increase the `font-size` of the brand? All tips are welcome!

Comment: can you provide the code to test

Comment: Try adding !important as Rahul said in him answer, it will overwrite the styles of the class you want to re-edit, but not all the class, only the attributes you write with "!important"

Comment: its working https://jsfiddle.net/MadhawaMB/m2fkLrtf/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just use `font-size: 100px !important;` hope this will be helpful for you.

Comment: Also consider relative sizes, such as `font-size:6.25rem`.

Comment: I am watching a tutorial....font-size: 100px worked for him but did not worked for me. using font-size: 100px !important worked for me. why this is so ?

Answer (score 11):

The font-size property specifies the size, or height, of the font. `font-size` affects not only the font to which it is applied, but is also used to compute the value of em, rem, and ex length units.
[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/MadhawaMB/m2fkLrtf/)
**Try like this**

```
.navbar-brand
{
  font-size: 100px;
}
```

**Absolute keywords and values**

```
.navbar-brand
    {
      font-size: larger;
    }
```

**It accepts the following absolute keyword values:**

```
xx-small

x-small

small

medium

large

x-large

xx-large
```

```css
h1 {
    font-size: 250%;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 200%;
}

p {
    font-size: 100%;
}
```

```html
<h1>MyAwesomeCompany</h1>
<h2>MyAwesomeCompany</h2>
<p>MyAwesomeCompany</p>
```

Answer (score 8):

You can do something like the following. It will not only make your brand-name a link but also will make it a heading. Easily change the font size by using a different heading tag (change h1 to h2, h3 etc). It will be efficient for search engines too.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
   <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><span class="mb-0 h1">Navbar</span></a>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2):

For Bootstrap > 5 you can use:

```
<span class="navbar-brand mb-0 h1 fs-2">Your Brand</span>
```

You have more info in: [Getbootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/text/#font-size)

I hope you find it useful